# How to access OLE Objects from MS Excel using Microsoft.Interop Excel

Tags: c#, excel, interop, openxml-sdk, epplus

I am trying to access a report which is a OLE Object(embedded into an Excel worksheet).

I am trying to do this from a C# console application using the Microsoft.Interop.Excel API.

I am successfully able to iterate through the OLE Objects present in a worksheet. **However, when i try to access the *Object* property of the OLEObject instance, i am getting a COM exception.**

Has anyone tried doing this before successfully. Please assist me with sample code.

Code i tried for POC as follows

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileName = string.Empty // some excel file path
        Application _excelApp = new Application();
        _excelApp.AutomationSecurity = MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable;

        Workbook workBook = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName,
     Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
     Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
     Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
     Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        for (int i = 1; i <= workBook.Sheets.Count; i++)
        {
            var sheet = workBook.Sheets[i] as Worksheet;

            try
            { 
                OLEObject obj = sheet.OLEObjects("BReport") as OLEObject;
                Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(obj.Object.ToString());                    
            }
            catch
            {                  
                continue;
            }
        }
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: @PhilipABarnes -> Edit the question with sample code..

Comment: the .ToString() method is specific to C# and might not handle well when used on a COM object. Try using Caption / Visible or other native properties to see if they work.

Comment: @PhilipABarnes -> The same code worked when i embedded PDF document.